# Couldn't open existing iPhone project with Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

My friend gave me his old iPhone app project files. I tried to open with my Xcode 4.2 but error message shows "cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed." then unable to open.

It doesn't have any space in project name. Does anyone know how to open this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your xcodeProject file is corrupted. you need to get it again. but first ensure that xcodeProject file is able to load project successfully from where you are receiving it again.

Comment: Thanks!! I guess you are right. Its corrupted because my other old projects have no problem to open.